# Angular2, Typescript,Json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am going to use angular2 platform to develop an application. I am stuck at one point that "How do I print nested json in Angular2 Component's template".

json file:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": "0000.55",
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

It's greatful if someone help me....:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json file in angular2 using multiple ngFor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314646/how-to-parse-json-file-in-angular2-using-multiple-ngfor)

Comment: What do you mean by print? Did you mean displaying JSON on your HTML template? Or getting the data from your json file to a variable?

Comment: Please give more detail about what you are trying to accomplish. Example: I'm trying to display the `batter` array inside the nested object in my html `<div>`.

Comment: print means, i want to display this json like below

Comment: 0001
 donut
 Cake
 0000.55
       1001    Regular       
       1002    Chocolate                    
topping
        5001    None
        5002    Glazed

Comment: Guys, thank u for observing my question. I am going to show menu and their submenu hierarchy on my template. and its solved by Mr Avnesh whose implementation is given below

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of jsonData">
    <div>{{obj.id}}</div>
    ...
    <div *ngFor="let bat of obj.batters.batter">
        <div>{{bat.id}}</div>
        <div>{{bat.type}}</div>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let topp of obj.topping">
        <div>{{topp.id}}</div>
        <div>{{topp.type}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can change your object:

```
 ...,
 "batters": [
    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
  ],
  ...
```

then you can do like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let bat of obj.batters">
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have tried it, but doesn't work for me. is there any other way like using pipes or something else.

Comment: Only the parent keys are visible i.e. id, name,type, ppu, batters. For child keys of batter and toppings, it returns [Object, Object], not values.

Comment: Update your question with template view how you trying.

Comment: Thank u Mr Avnesh Shakya. there is my error thats why its not executing. now its solved. Thank U very much.